# CgridView to display an Image instead of text

Tags: php, yii

What i am trying to do is to have this CGridView inside of the Yii framework get Data from my **Image** table from the database where it consist of **imageUrl** and **imageExtension** tables. Now i want to just display the actual image form the directory then just the text.

Meaning i have to join **imageUrl** and **imageExtension** together and also make the path in front to display the image tag.

Is this possible with the CGridView?

Here is my CGridView code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'image-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'imageUrl',
            'imageExtension',
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize `CGridView` columns.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'image-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
             'header'=>'MY IMAGES',
             'name'=>'imageUrl',
             'value'=>'CHtml::image($data->imageUrl.$data->imageExtension)',
             'type'=>'raw'
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

By the following array:

```
array(
             'header'=>'MY IMAGES',
             'name'=>'imageUrl',
             'value'=>'CHtml::image($data->imageUrl.$data->imageExtension)',
             'type'=>'raw'
        ),
```

You tell yii, to build a column with `MY IMAGES` header and show the value of column as an image with: `'value'=>'CHtml::image($data->imageUrl.$data->imageExtension)'`. `'type'=>'raw'` means that you are trying to tell yii, not to show the text.